# Issue Related to Overlapping .Net Controls in WindowsXP

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have developed a windows Application in .Net2010 in Windows 7, Windows Forms and Controls looks Perfact in Windows 7, but in WindowsXP Text containing in Textbox hides first character overlaps between Label and Textbox as shown in Following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Label controls that you're using to provide a caption for each of the TextBox and ComboBox controls are extending out over the top of the TextBox and ComboBox controls. Their background color is the same as your form (the brownish-gray color).

One possible solution is to change the Z order of your controls so that the Label controls are always in the background. The controls will still overlap, but the TextBox and ComboBox controls will overlap the Label controls instead of the other way around.

That would work fine as long as there was no *text* on the Label controls getting covered up. That's rather unlikely, and you certainly count on it. Instead, you need to redesign your form so that there is plenty of extra space between controls. You can't jam things up that close to one another, or there won't be any room for expansion and they'll have no choice but to overlap.

Move the controls around and give them some breathing room.  The aptly-named `Padding` property is very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TableLayoutPanel` to place your controls in a good manner
[Go here to read about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel.aspx).

With this you could use `Docking` and `Anchoring` properties of those controls to grow or shrink them as the space changes.